# UI- Router -- run function on every route change -- where does the state name live?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using Angularjs and UI-Router, trying to run a function every time state changes

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(toState){
            if(toState !== 'login')
            UsersService.redirect();
        })
```

I put this in .run() and i can successfully log out toState every time route changes. However, i can't seem to find the property which has the name of the state that we are going to. If someone can tell me where to find that, i think i should be in good shape.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ended up with this and it does what i want.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            if(toState.name !== 'login' && !UsersService.getCurrentUser()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
            }
        });
```