# How to execute a controller before loading templateUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to execute a controller before loading step1.html.

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router","ngResource"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("step1", {
              url : "/",
              templateUrl : "easyquote/step1.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            })       


            .state("step2", {
              url : "/step2",
              templateUrl : "easyquote/step2.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            })
    }]
    );
}());
```

I want to create controller in autoQuoteCtrl.js file. and execute funtion on load initializeapp

```
.controller("initializeapp", ["$rootScope",function($rootScope,event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
         console.log('do on page load'+event+'\n'+toParams+'\n'+fromState+'\n'+fromParams);
    });
}]);
```

This function I want execute on page load or whenever user refresh page. but it executes on each state change.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24357286/1867608

Comment: Thanks. where should I write this code?

Comment: After config, anywhere you can get the $scope. You can write a controller A and have `<body ng-controller="A">', so that it will execute at once.

Comment: updated question initializeapp function , but it executes on each state change, I wan this should execute only on page load.

Comment: Checkout `$viewContentLoaded` here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score -1):

We can use the angular.element(document).ready() method to attach callbacks for when the document is ready. We can simply attach the callback in the controller.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router","ngResource"]);
    .controller('autoQuoteCtrl.js', [function() {
angular.element(document).ready(function () {

});
app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("step1", {
          url : "/",
          templateUrl : "easyquote/step1.html",
          controller: "questionsCtrl",
        })       


        .state("step2", {
          url : "/step2",
          templateUrl : "easyquote/step2.html",
          controller: "questionsCtrl",
        })
}]
);
 }());
```