# Restrict certain AngularJS routes for given NodeJS route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have two routes added to my NodeJS backend server app.js file as follows:

```
// Add the routes
app.get('/provision', ...);
app.get('/', ...);
```

Either of these routes gives full access to all the routes defined in AngularJS:

```
function routes($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/list',
        {
            templateUrl: 'sections/list/list.tpl.html',
            controller: 'listController',
            controllerAs: 'listCtrl'
        })
        .when('/overview',
        {
            templateUrl: 'sections/overview/overview.tpl.html',
            controller: 'overviewController',
            controllerAs: 'overviewCtrl'
        })
...
```

Just for example: I would like to control for "/provision" route in NodeJS to be able to access only "/list" route in AngularJS and for "/" route in NodeJS to be able to access only "/overview" route in AngularJS.

Currently in my code, I am able to access all the AngularJS routes from browser using "/provision" or "/" route defined in NodeJS. I would like to access only certain angularJS routes for "/provision" and the rest with "/" route. How can I control that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using angular routing, you probably don't need to be using anything but the * route in Node except for api calls. You can use the stateChangeStart lifecycle method to determine if the user should be allowed to an angular route however. Some explanation of how to do this is found here [UI- Router -- run function on every route change -- where does the state name live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357286/ui-router-run-function-on-every-route-change-where-does-the-state-name-li)

So to reiterate you wouldn't use both node and angular to handle routing. You'd have a * route which will allow ui router to handle all of the routing. You can use stateChangeStart to determine if the user is allowed to go where they are trying to go, and if not you can redirect them.